# Does the client and webserver need to have cross domain access enabled?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, cross-domain

I'm currently developing a PC webserver that would access my MCU webserver using this code.

The PC and the MCU are connected in the same network.
Whenever, I try to send a GET REQUEST through jquery to my MCU server I get no response. Though I see that the request was received at the MCU, there is no response received in my PC webserver.

Could it be because I have a problem about cross domain access? But why? They're just connected to the same network right?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
?>
<head>

    <script src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>$(document).ready(function()
        { 
            $("button").click(function()
            {    
                $.get("192.168.1.102/",function(data,status)
                {     
                    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);   
                });  
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <button>Send an HTTP GET request to a page and get the result back</button>
</body>
</html>
```

My MCU webserver doesn't have a file index.html or .php but IT DOES SEND a string when a GET or POST request is received.

Here is the string that it sends:

```
#define HTTP_HEAD "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" \
    "Content-Type: text/html\r\n" \
    "Connection: Close\r\n" \
    "Content-Length: 1121\r\n\r\n" \
    "<!DOCTYPE html>" \
    "<html>" \
        "<head>" \
            "<style>" \
                    "#content{color: red; font-size: 50px;top: 70px;}" \
            "</style>" \
        "</head>" \
            "<body>" \
            "<center>" \
            "<div id='content'>" 

#define HTTP_TAIL "</center></body></html>\r\n\r\n"
```

Do I also need my MCU webserve to have cross domain access or is it just my PC webserver that needs it to access the MCU webserver?

Here is my result for monitoring both the PC webserver and the MCU webserver.
The MCU webserver response seems to lack other headers since it only stops at the `Content-length: 1121`

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

for that you should enable cores in client side as well.
example,

```
    $.support.cors = true;
     $.ajax({
        crossDomain: true,
        type: "POST",
        url: "url"

    }).done(function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Anoop! I will try that, but for now I want to share to you the results I've found when monitoring both the PC webserver where the GET request is from, and the MCU webserver where the GET req is received.

[here is the link] [http://i149.photobucket.com/albums/s48/vash1102/guide/debug_zpsea78cafd.png?t=1392896863]

I'm just wondering why the response given by the MCU stopped at the Content-length: 1121 hmmm.....